# Android Studio layout preview breaks with too many includes

Tags: android-studio

I have an XML layout including many times the same layout. Turns out you can't include the same layout more than 50 times without breaking the preview renderer.
Here is the error that I get:
`Exception raised during rendering: Cycle found (count=51)`

Would there be a way to get around this?
It works fine on device.
The guys developing Android Studio ought to set this arbitrary limit much higher really.
More like 500 maybe.

Found the [code](https://github.com/JetBrains/android/blob/b373163869f676145341d60985cdbdaca3565c0b/android/src/com/android/tools/idea/rendering/LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java#L139) that's limiting the number of includes to 50.

Answer (score 0):

Just including a different layout once works around that problem. I just duplicated the included layout for now. I think that fouls there broken cycling dependency detection somehow.

Therefore this is only an issue when including more than 50 times the same layout file without including any other layout. As long as you include another layout you still can include any one of them as many times as you want without breaking the preview renderer.

That ought to be reported to JetBrains.
Opened that [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/267801025).